# Issue configuring proxy settings with NTLM authentication on Amazon SDK

Tags: java, proxy, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm using amazon SDK 1.5.6 and trying to initialize the connection using a proxy server.
The initialization succeed, but when I try to use the `AmazonEC2Client` it fails with the following 
error:

> Caught Exception: Status Code: 407, AWS Service: AmazonEC2, AWS
>   Request ID: null, AWS Error Code: 407 Unauthorized, AWS Error Message:
>   Unable to unmarshall error response (Premature end of file.) Reponse
>   Status Code: 407 Error Code: 407 Unauthorized Request ID: null

Initialization code:

```
protected AmazonEC2 initAmazonSDKClient(String endpoint) {

        AWSCredentials awsCredentials =
                new BasicAWSCredentials(_account.getAccessKey(), _account.getSecretKey());
        ClientConfiguration config = getProxySettings();
        AmazonEC2 ret = CloudServicesEC2Api.getAmazonEC2Client(awsCredentials, config);
        ret.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        _endPointToAmazonEC2Client.put(endpoint, ret);

        return ret;
    }

private ClientConfiguration getProxySettings() {

        ClientConfiguration ret = new ClientConfiguration();
        String host = _proxySettings.getServer();
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(host )) {
            ret.setProxyHost(host );
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(_proxySettings.getPort())) {
            ret.setProxyPort(Integer.valueOf(_proxySettings.getPort()));
        }
        String proxyUserName = _proxySettings.getUserName();
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(proxyUserName)) {
            ret.setProxyUsername(proxyUserName);
        }
        String proxyPassword = _proxySettings.getPassword();
        if (!StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(proxyPassword)) {
            ret.setProxyPassword(proxyPassword);
        }
        ret.setProxyWorkstation(host );
        ret.setProxyDomain(host );

        return ret;
    }
```

Code that uses the client and causes the error:

```
private List<InstanceStatus> getStatusChecks(AmazonEC2 ec2Client, String[] hostIds) {

        DescribeInstanceStatusRequest describeInstanceRequest =
                new DescribeInstanceStatusRequest().withInstanceIds(hostIds);
        DescribeInstanceStatusResult describeInstanceResult =
                ec2Client.describeInstanceStatus(describeInstanceRequest);

        return describeInstanceResult.getInstanceStatuses();
    }
```

I know the root cause is the NTLM authentication, I need to somehow configure the NTLM host & NTLM domain, in my code sample its the lines:

```
ret.setProxyWorkstation(host );
ret.setProxyDomain(host );
```

I have tried several versions of workstation & domain, i tried leaving it blank, no use...

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research it turns out that something is not right in the way Amazon SDK handles NTLM proxy requests. We've compared the proxy parameters passed to other libraries (e.g JClouds) where the connection succeeded and tried applying the same on Amazon SDK with no luck. 
We have even compared the packets using wireshark, everything is the same. Something is just not right with this library...